# How to create a top-level page with Notion API?

Tags: notion-api

How do you create a page at the top level (workspace).

I know there is "type" of "workspace", but that only seems evident when retrieving such a page. The page-adding endpoint requires a parent ID. So how can I create a page at workspace level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't supported. Pages must have a parent page or database.

Comment: Update 2022 August : This still seems to be case